# @ConditionalOnProperty Bean configuration not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, conditional-statements

For a simple spring boot app i'm face an unexpected behavior when tring to instatiate beans conditionnaly

I have defined in my application.yml the conditional flag: service.enable=true

Then I created ServiceMesh.java interface, which should be implemented by serviceA and serviceB as below:

```
public interface ServiceMesh {
}

public class ServiceA implements ServiceMesh{
// ... code
}

public class ServiceB implements ServiceMesh{
// ... code
}
```

*I defined also a configuration class:*

```
@Configuration
public class ConditionOnPropertyConfiguration {

@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "service", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true")
public ServiceMesh from(){
    return new ServiceA();
  }

@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "service", name = "enabled", havingValue = "false")
public ServiceMesh from(Environment env){
    return new ServiceB();
  }
}
```

When running my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I got this error:
No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo.service.ServiceMesh' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Expected behavior is to start application

Answer (score 1):

Change method names `from` to `serviceA` and `serviceB`. I have changed property definition from `service.enable=true` to  `service.enabled=true`.

```java
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "service", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true")
    public ServiceMesh serviceA() {
        return new ServiceA();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "service", name = "enabled", havingValue = "false")
    public ServiceMesh serviceB() {
        return new ServiceB();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it seams to be a bypass for the real problem, if you take a look to ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader#loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod, you will see that its skips bean definition if config class already has skipped a method with the same name; this behavior is not documented any where.